# Cloning a repo from Azure DevOps at a client

Tags: ssl, vpn, azure, repository, azure-devops

We are running into a weird issue while cloning a repo from Azure DevOps at a client.

Error: RPC failed; curl 56 Failure when receiving data from the peer

So far we tried;

```
  git config settings - SSLbackedn, sslVerify, postBuffer, proxy.
  We also tried being on client's VPN and without VPN. (just fyi - we received machines from client, that is where we are currently working and having issues)
```

Please let me know if anyone dealt with this issue before and have any suggestions that we can try. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be some configuration at your client site having issues with the outbound connection to Git, probably some sort of SSL intercept or similar meaning the HTTPS validation is failing.